# get google calendar reminders using php

Tags: php, notifications, calendar, google-calendar-api, reminders

I have integrated google calender in my php based web application.

I have just pasted `<iframe>`, which I got from my google calendar console and it displays well all events.

Now I want to get popup notification before 10 mins of each event. I have set notification time for my events too.

But at that time what happens is:

If my web app tab is open in browser, then also it goes to calendar console tab of browser and there displays alert message, that you have an upcoming event. I want to display this notification alert in my web application.

How to do this?

Comment: Have you referred to their OAuth and API docs? You should be able to auth yourself and pull events using API or ICAL.

Comment: I am able to pull events using API too , but I dont want event list , I just want popup notification before 10 mins of each event. how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body) wherein in the request body, you can use the `reminders.overrides[].minutes` property. It states the number of minutes before the start of the event when the reminder should trigger.

> To override the default reminders when you insert of modify an event, set [`reminders.useDefault`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#reminders.useDefault) to false and populate [`reminders.overrides`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#reminders.overrides) with the new reminder set.
>
> ```
> "reminders": {
>   "useDefault": "useDefault",
>   # Overrides can be set if and only if useDefault is false.
>   "overrides": [
>       {
>         "method": "reminderMethod",
>         "minutes": "reminderMinutes"
>       },
>       # ...
>   ]
> }
> ```

Check the examples [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events#metadata).